# Syntax of attaching a variable to an alter command

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working in SQL Server version 17.9.1

I have had issues getting the Database Diagram tool to work. I found the code here to Alter Authorization on database.  The code worked fine.  My problem is I have several databases that I need to refresh with stored procedures I have built.  I have a variable that needs to be attached to the alter statement but am not familiar with the syntax of the code to do that.

The variable is called `@TrainDB1`.

The alter command is

```
Alter AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::NorthWindlev3 TO sa;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic SQL so you can pass in your variable to use on the *alter authorization* statement

Here is an example

```
declare @DBName nvarchar(max) = 'someDb', @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
select @SQL = 'Alter AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::' + quotename(@DBName) + ' TO sa'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: This would be quite an injection issue like this, and I don't doubt that this is why it has a downvote. When injecting, you should ensure that you properly quote dynamic objects.

Comment: @larnu updated to use quotename to take care of that.